# Is a transit visa required when travelling from UK to New Zealand via Sydney?

Tags: air-travel, visas, australia, transit, new-zealand

Do I need a transit visa when travelling from UK to New Zealand stopping in Sydney for one hour 30 minutes?

Comment: Is it on a through ticket, or do you have to collect your bags and re-check them with a new airline?

Answer (score 6):

According to the [Australian department of immigration](http://www.immi.gov.au/visitors/transit/no-visa.htm), you need a transit visa unless all of the following conditions are met:

- Your stop lasts no longer than 8 hours (ok).
- You remain in the transit area (so not ok if you need to retrieve and check in your luggage in Sydney).
- You must have an accepted passport. Mostly this means you are from Europe, Oceania or North America (but check [this page](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/transit-771/travellers-eligible-to-transit-without-visa) for the exact list of countries).

Otherwise, you must get a [transit visa](http://www.immi.gov.au/visitors/transit/771/). It's free, but you must apply in advance, after booking your flight and if necessary obtaining a visa for your destination.

Comment: Does this 8 hour stop take delays into consideration? It says on the link `within 8 hours of the scheduled time of their arrival`, but what if the flight turns up late and you have a connecting flight booked?

Comment: @ing0 If you miss your connecting flight, you may need to obtain a visa on the spot. I expect that this is common enough that there will be a customs officer present who knows what to do.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was more curious if our flight was delayed for something that was out of our control. I imagine that in this case I wouldn't be the only traveller without a transit visa and stuck in AUS for potentially more than 8 hours. Do they issue them on the spot under certain circumstances? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a transit visa for Sydney as you can see [here](http://www.immi.gov.au/visitors/transit/no-visa.htm). UK is included in the list of countries that doesn't need it.

Also if you hold a British passport you are included.

> Transit without visa arrangements
>
> 3.- People holding British passports (irrespective of endorsement in
> passport regarding national status)

Comment: @downvoter can you at least leave me a comment to know what is it wrong in my answer? Thanks

Comment: The link is appropriate, but what you state is very different from what that web page states.

Comment: @Gilles Thank you. I gave him the answer according to his conditions, he is on transit for 1h 30m and I was assuming he is holding British passport (At the moment the question doesn't specify it). So I left the answer for his case, though I agree it could have been expressed better.